# Find the sum of the digits entered number [cmd]

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, console

Write a script that:

• prompts the user for a string of random characters, including numbers

• is the sum of digits entered number

The string entered by the user and stored in the variable. The program should be in the loop all the characters (one), and then add them as numbers.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
chcp 1251>nul
set /p string=^>
set symbol=0
set summa=0
:sum
if "!string:~%symbol%,1!"=="" (goto :result) else (set element=!string:~%symbol%,1!)
set /a summa=!summa!+!element!
set /a symbol=!symbol!+1
goto :sum
:result
echo.sum: [!summa!]
pause>nul
```

Program must be addressed through a for loop

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Added an example in the description

Comment: [FOR - Conditionally perform a command several times.](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: The very surprised by this, because there are more suitable for this purpose means, such as the C programming language :)

Comment: Get first character and rest of `%string%` by `set "char=%string:~0,1%"` and `set "string=%string:~1%"`, respectively. And now you could test whether `%char%` is a _cipher_ in a `for` loop...